# Rewrite URL on submit form

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a search form and when I make a search I get this URL "http://****/video/view/search/?imeto_tam=tarsene" but I want to replace this the "?imeto_tam=tarsene" with the word I search for and my address to look like this - "http://****/video/view/search/tarsene". Generally I use mod_rewrite on my site and it's working for my links but it's not working for the form-s. Could someone tell me how to do it?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9a-zA-Z\-\(\)]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9a-zA-Z\-():]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-():\.,]+)$ index.php?a=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I don’t quite get what you want. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

These rules would go into your root .htaccess file and 301 redirect the querystring imeto_tam to the folder and then the next rule would make it get passed to your code (index.php)

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?imeto_tam=([^&]+)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^video/view/search/(index\.php)?$ /video/view/search/%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^video/view/search/([^/]+)/$ /video/view/search/index\.php?imeto_tam=$1 [L]
```